# Dotnet - Kafka SSL Connectivity Issue

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka

**Issue 1:**
We are trying to connect from a DOTNET client (3.1) to Kafka. While doing so, we are running into the below issue:

```
      SSL handshake unsuccessful. AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
{2023-11-03T00:01:24.738Z} fail: XXX.Server.Startup[0]
      Inner exception: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
```

We are not seeing any other error after that.

**Issue 2:**
When trying to replicate this from the local, using this command:

```
dotnet run --host ws://asfd12314.afr.com:5000  --kafka-caller-topic ABCD-CALLER --kafka-agent-topic ABCD-AGENT --kafka-bootstrap-servers kafka-dev.abc.com:4492 --kafka-security-protocol SSL --kafka-ssl-keystore-location certs/kafka_dev.p12 --kafka-ssl-keystore-password password123 --kafka-ssl-key-password password123 --kafka-ssl-ca-location certs/XXX.crt
```

we see the below error

```
{2023-11-03T09:31:58.606Z} warn: RViss.Server.Startup[0]
      Tried test SSL handshake with broker and failed: Interop+AppleCrypto+AppleCommonCryptoCryptographicException: Unknown format in import.
         at Interop.AppleCrypto.X509ImportCertificate(Byte[] bytes, X509ContentType contentType, SafePasswordHandle importPassword, SafeKeychainHandle keychain, Boolean exportable, SafeSecIdentityHandle& identityHandle)
```

When I searched on StackOverflow, I realized that it is because the P12 file should be part of the login keychain on my Mac. I am on a Mac M1 and when I try to run the below command to add it to my keychain, I am seeing the below error:

```
messi@12312a certs % security import "/Users/messi/ws/microsoft-stt-app/host/certs/kafka_dev.p12" -k "/Users/messi/Library/KeyChains/login.keychain-db"

security: SecKeychainItemImport: Unknown format in import.
```

It didn't help when I tried converting the `.p12` to a `.cer` either.

Would appreciate any help w/ either of the issues. I can add any information for issue 1 as necessary.